# Hacker's Keyboard is ignored now, it tells me I have to unlock the phone?

Tags: keyboard

Somehow my phone is not showing me my Hacker's Keyboard anymore. It's saying that it could send all the info I type to a 3rd party (which is technically correct, I would imagine...)

It used to work, I installed a new app. and after about a month it managed to prevent the keyboard from showing up. I went to the settings and turned the keyboard back on (ah! it looks like it was turned off on me...) That step told me that it would work only if I were to unlock my phone and reboot.

So how do I do that and is that specific to just this app or would it allow (unlock) any app. from doing what it wants? Is Android that lame?

Comment: Have you tried clearing its cache and/or data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well! I'm not sure why, but somehow my *Default Keyboard* setup was back to the Samsung keyboard (the default). So I guess there was a new version which was updated and after updating, the *Default keyboard* switch was back to the default.

Editing that one setting and the Hacker's Keyboard was back in business.

The selection of the *Default Keyboard* on my phone is available from "Settings" > "General Management" > "Language and Input"

Comment: Is this an answer to your question?

Comment: @Beveloper, I thought so. Is there a problem with it?

Comment: not really,  but if you don't mind I did an edit and you should mark your answer as the accepted.

Comment: @Beveloper, Ah, yes, thank you. Often the "accepted" flag can't be clicked right away... I've done so now.